# Generating a matlab plot from an wpf project on C# only works sometimes

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, matlab, plot

I'm trying to generate a plot using MLapp class in a C# project.
It works sometimes, but others it gets stuck and doesn't output anything.
I have added a reference to the COM server of the Matlab Application.

That is the code which I'm using:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private MLApp.MLApp matlab;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
            matlab.Visible = 0;
        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            matlab.Quit();
        }
        private void Click_Plot1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            matlab.Execute("s = sin(linspace(0,10,100)); plot(s);");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a syntax error in your MainWindow.

Delete the `plot(s);");` Or Change it to  `matlab.Execute("s = sin(linspace(0,10,100)); plot(s);");` etc.

There is only just one double quote and one parenthesis.

Comment: I checked that but it gives me a syntax error if I put like that. I dont know if I undertand well. You mean that I sould delete one of the double quote at this expresion, no? I dont think that is a syntax error, maybe it is something of the COM server of matlab but I dont know it.

Comment: I mean your line is all redundant. Compared to `matlab.Execute("s = sin(linspace(0,10,100)); plot(s);");`, it seems that s is not defined. And it doesn't have a corresponding `("`. I don't know much about matlab, but I haven't seen such a way of writing from my searches.

Comment: Ah, sorry!!!!! I have seen what line you are talking about. I think I didnt copy well my code. I will checked if I have this line in my file. Anyways, without it, I have the same problem when I try to execute something using the command "execute". When i tried it a few times it didnt execute the matlab command everytime.

Comment: Can you copy well and edit the question? so that I can help you with your problem.

Comment: Yes, I changed the main method and put it well, and add the missing curly brackets